# Assign items to a minimal number of groups

Tags: algorithm, math

This is a popular CS pattern, but I'm apparently missing some keywords because I'm not having any luck searching for it.

I have a set of 4 items: [A,B,C,D].

I have 3 groups: 1, 2, 3.

Group 1 can accept A or B.

Group 2 can accept B or C.

Group 3 can accept C or D.

Assign the items in a way that minimizes the number of groups used. 
I.e. the solution would be:
Group 1: [A,B]

Group 2: []

Group 3: [C,D]

How would I solve this programatically? I know I've seen this before, so any keywords or links to point me in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the set covering problem. It is NP hard, so finding the true minimal set is hard in general and requires exponential time. The greedy algorithm which takes the set covering the most remaining elements may give good approximations. For covering sets with bounded size it can be also solved in reasonable time. For further details see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Answer (score 1):

If we visualize this problem as a Graph problem, which all the groups and items are nodes in the graph, and there are edges connect between the group and items, we can see that this problem is a small case of [Vertex Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)

However, if the number of items is small (less than 16), we can use dynamic programming to solve it easily.